# ‘precision_at_target_recall’, ‘recall_at_target_precision’ on hyper parameters on AWS SageMaker , how does it train with that constraint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, linear-regression, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

[AWS SageMaker LinearLearner][1] ;  **binary_classifier_model_selection_criteria** is a hyper parameter useful without having cross validation and hyper param tuning. At least it seems to me so.

If yes , can you please explain how a model can be trained with having that hyper parameter be set to **‘precision_at_target_recall’** or **‘recall_at_target_precision'** ?

I have not seen such a thing in scikit-learn. The only way it seems possible and reasonable to me is to play with threshold to keep it at the level of target_recall or target_precision, unfortunately nothing is mentioned about the threshold or cut off in documentation and Ii guess it is still at .5.

Comment: I assume it's based on setting a threshold; see "Step 3: Validate and set the threshold" in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ll_how-it-works.html
But I would be happy to see more concrete documentation on that!

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker Linear Learner is different from open-source linear models in multiple aspects, in particular:

- **More control on performance**: It features [hyperparameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ll_hyperparameters.html) to force the model to respect a given precision or recall threshold. For example, if your goal is to get a classifier that gets at least 95% recall, you can choose hyperparameters accordingly: `binary_classifier_model_selection_criteria='precision_at_target_recall'` and `target_recall=0.95`
- **It can explore multiple configurations in a single training job**, effectively doing "tuning-in-training". This behavior is called "parallel training and model selection" in the documentation, is different than the SageMaker Model Tuning feature and is specific to the Linear Learner. You can control the number of tested models with the `num_models` parameter
- **It is usually much more scalable than alternatives:** it is trained like a neural network in mini-batch SGD fashion, allowing it to support data-parallel distributed training over multiple CPUs or GPUs instances. It supports PIPE-mode data loading, a SageMaker low-latency, high-throughput data ingest technique that uses Unix named pipe to stream data from S3 directly in memory, allowing to learn on immense datasets too big for local disks.
- **It was designed to be highly efficient** we can only speculate what the underlying tricks are, since the implementation is not public, but I believe the rich SGD customization options and the tuning-in-training design contribute to its economic performance. See below a benchmark vs MLlib from the paper *[Elastic Machine Learning Algorithms in Amazon SageMaker](https://edoliberty.github.io/papers/sagemaker.pdf)* by Liberty et al
- **It comes with a built-in serving stack**: you can easily deploy a trained model to a SageMaker-managed serving endpoint, without having to write any dockerfile or webserver code yourself

[image]

An additional notable difference of the SageMaker Linear Learner compared to the other SageMaker Built-in is that you can read it out of SageMaker with the MXNet deserialization code provided in the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ll_how-it-works.html)